# fadein fadeout javascript slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to create a simple fade in fade out image slideshow in javascript. Ive managed to create one that shows one image, fades out and then fades another image in but this is not what im going for. What i want is so that when the first image fades out, there is already another image behind it and when the other image also fades out, theres another image behind that one too. Im trying to avoid having the part of the webpage that holds the slideshow from being empty at any time during the slideshow. Can anyone help me out by editing my code or showing me how I can achieve this?

```
var count = 1;
setInterval(function(){
if (count <= 3){
    $("#slideshow").fadeOut(2000);
    setTimeout(function(){$("#slideshow").attr("src","breakup/"+ count +".jpg")},2000);
    $("#slideshow").fadeIn(2000);
    count++;

    if (count>3){
    count = 1
    }
}//end if
}/*end function*/,5000);
```

Comment: you can't use 1 `img` element to do that, you need 2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably easiest to pre-load all of your images

css:

```
<style>
    .slider{
       position: relative;
    }

    img {
       position: absolute;
       top:0;
       left:0;
    }
</style>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
var count = 1
setInterval(function(){
  var old= $('#img-' + count);
  old.fadeOut(2000);

  count++;
  if (count>3){
    count = 1
  }

  var next= $('#img-' + count);
  next.fadeIn(2000);
}, 5000);


</script>
```

html:

```
<div class="slider">
   <img id="img-1" src="breakup/1.jpg">
   <img id="img-2" src="breakup/2.jpg">
   <img id="img-3" src="breakup/3.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/wfvD6/.

Basically it clones the old image and put it over the new image, then fadeout old and fadein new at the same time.

```
    //clone the old image
    var ghost = slider.clone();

    //remove id
    ghost.removeAttr('id');

    //make the ghost image just over the old image
    var pos = slider.position();
    ghost.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: pos.top,
        left: pos.left
    });
    ghost.insertBefore(slider);

    //$("#slideshow").attr("src","breakup/"+ count+".jpg");

    //change image
    setImage(count);

    //fadeout ghost
    ghost.fadeOut(2000, function () {
        ghost.remove();
        ghost = null;
    });

    //fadein slider
    slider.fadeIn(2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xmLk4/ You should set the images for slide 1 and 2 after the fadeout in order to allow loading of the image before it fades in.

```
function fade(){

    $("#slide2").fadeOut(2000, function() {

        // set new image slide 2

    }).delay(2000).fadeIn(2000, function() {

        // set new image slide 1

    }).delay(2000);

}

setInterval(fade, 8000);

fade();
```